# How Does Bundler Determine to Re-Install Something?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, bundler

I'm using a CI tool (CircleCI to be specific) to cache some Ruby gems so I don't have to re-install them on every build. Currently on the first build I'm doing this:

```
gem install bundler
bundle install
```

Which installs a number of gems:

```
Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/..........
Resolving dependencies...
Using public_suffix 3.0.2
Using addressable 2.5.2
Using bundler 1.16.1
Using mini_mime 1.0.0
Using mini_portile2 2.3.0
Fetching nokogiri 1.8.2
Installing nokogiri 1.8.2 with native extensions
```

Once that initial build is done I'm caching the directory which bundler shows where the gems are: `/opt/circleci/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/` and its contents.

The next time it runs I can do `cd /opt/circleci/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/` and reveal all of the gems from the cache that were restored. However if I navigate to my Gemfile and run `bundle info nokogiri` or any of the other gems in that folder it reveals an error: `Could not find public_suffix-3.0.2 in any of the sources`

If I run `bundle install` or `gem install gemnamehere` the gems install *again* which is not ideal because the goal is to save time on the build. Do I need to run some sort of command with bundle or Ruby to let it know that these gems are installed so it doesn't do it again?

Apologies if this is a silly question, I'm learning this as I go along.

Edit: CircleCI config as requested:

```
  test:
    machine: true
    steps:  
      - run:
          # Installs PhantomJS
          name: Install phantomjs
          command: |
            if ! [ $(which phantomjs) ]; then                
              curl --output /usr/local/bin/phantomjs https://s3.amazonaws.com/circle-downloads/phantomjs-2.1.1
            fi
      - checkout
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      - run:
          name: "Install Dependencies"
          command: |
            cd ~/project
            gem install bundler
            bundle install
      - save_cache:
          key: v1-gem-cache-{{ arch }}-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
          paths:
            - /opt/circleci/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1/gems/
      - run:
          name: "Run  Snapshots"
          command: |
            cd ~/project
            yarn build
            cd ~/project/mocks/visual
            bundle exec ruby snapshots.rb
```

Comment: Have you tried first doing `bundle check` ?

Comment: Just did, and end up with a list of missing gems, those included are the ones I end up having to re-install.

Comment: can you post your `circle/config.yml` and obfuscate things you don't want published?

Comment: @lacostenycoder Done

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution was to use `bundle install --path vendor/cache` and cache the `vendor/cache` path instead.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try changing this part?

```
- save_cache:
      key: v1-tc-gem-cache-{{ .Branch }}-{{ checksum "Gemfile.lock" }}
      paths:
        - vendor/bundle
  - persist_to_workspace:
      root: ~/project
      paths: vendor/bundle
```

Comment: This doesn't work, I end up with `The specified paths did not match any files in /home/circleci/project`.